# How to Append videos in Unity3D programmatically

Tags: c#, android, ios, unity-game-engine

I am working in a unity3d video gallery app.
I need to upload and download videos from server. 
Can i append four videos in Unity3D programmatically and upload.

Please suggest me the solution. I will be highly obliged.

Comment: Please describe your issue more detailed. What exactly do you want t archive "append four videos in Unity3D programmatically"? Concatenate videos?

Comment: @shallowThought 
Thanks for your comment,
Yes, i want to append four videos in Unity3D programmatically

Answer (score 1):

I order to load video from a server or from your local filesystem that is not directly in your *asset* folder you need to use **WWW**.

Here is the example from the documentation for an image but it works the same way with a video:

```
public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    public string url = "http://images.earthcam.com/ec_metros/ourcams/fridays.jpg";
    IEnumerator Start() {
        WWW www = new WWW(url);
        yield return www;
        Renderer renderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();
        renderer.material.mainTexture = www.texture;
    }
}
```

Here is a link to the Unity documentation: [WWW](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html)

Comment: Thanks But Can i append four videos in Unity3D programmatically

Comment: @ManuGupta Yes you just have to set the texture on four objects

Comment: I think @ManuGupta is asking for a solution to append video files into one video file and then upload them via Unity C#, this solution may not be what he's looking for as it only loads the video to play it inside Unity.